# How to select which view is resized by the adjustResize android keyboard attribute

Tags: android, keyboard

I want a viewA to be resize by the keyboard and the viewB to be hidden when the keyboard appears : see the attached picture

In the manifest I used the following attribute : "**adjustResize**"

I saw some post about checking if the keyboard is shown and change the viewB visibility to "GONE" but it doesn't seems very good regarding the animation of the keyboard..

Does anyone have an idea to make it works ? A way to keek the viewB in the bottom hidden by the keyboard ?

[image]

Comment: put the xml code in a scrollview

Comment: Hi, I tried to put a scrollview around the viewB or around the viewA, in both cases, the viewB is visible..

Comment: No i mean you have a parent layout say linearlayout so put that whole code in a scrollview then check. Mind that scrollview can contain only one child.

Comment: I tried with the parent view surrounded by a scrollview but it's not working, i really need the bottom of the viewA to be collapsed with the keyboard..

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer?

Comment: Do you have solution for this?